# Master Reference Tables

Tags: ibm-information-server

We have master reference data tables that I can -

Define the table to Information Analyzer

Profile the data in the table

Define values in this table as values for a reference data table

Use these values in the project to check other table column values

What I would like to know is -

where can you see a catalogue of these tables

administer and publish this content

where can I see it as an asset in business glossary

if I can see the reference table asset in BG can I browse the values of the table

As far as I can see the answer to all those points is you can’t is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The reference tables are listed in Information Analyzer under the Investigate > Table Management menu.  You can open/view the values in these tables there.  There is an option to Export when you open the tables which could be used to Publish.  (However, for a full reference data solution for administering and publishing content, I'd turn to our Reference Data Management product.)

The reference tables are identified with a specific category (I think 'Domain and Completeness' if I recall correctly) in the Table Management screen.
These tables were primarily designed for internal use, though certainly visible and named under the IADB database.

If you import the metadata for the IADB as a distinct source (a needed step if you are using the named output tables option in the IA rules), then the reference tables will be visible in BG or Metadata Workbench as an asset.  As with any such metadata references you cannot browse the values in the tables there (just like you wouldn't be able to browse the values of your customer master table from BG). 
Hope that helps.